# Orthogonal Transformations and Eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonality

True or false: There exists and orthogonal matrix $T$ that has 2 as an eigenvalue.

I think this is false, but I do not know how to prove it

Comment: If $Tx=2x$, does it look like $T$ preserves the norm of every vector?

Comment: What is your definition of orthogonal matrix?

Comment: It preserves the length of vectors (definition from my textbook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suppose $\lambda,$ a real number,  is an eigenvalue of $T.$ we will show that $$\lambda = \pm 1, \text{ that is }\lambda \neq 2.  $$

we have $$Tx = \lambda x, x\ \neq 0.\tag 1$$ multiplying (1) by $(Tx)^\top =\lambda x^\top $ on the left we have $$x^\top T^\top T x = x^\top x = \lambda^2 x^\top x \implies \lambda^2 = 1 \text{ or } \lambda = \pm 1.   $$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If $T$ is orthogonal, then $\langle Tx,Tx \rangle = \langle x,x \rangle$ for every $x$.